# Almacenar informacion en un array y mostrarla

Tags: c, array, scanf

Tengo un código sobre peliculas que tienen sus tipos en el cual busco almacenar su información en un array.

A la hora de recoger los datos debo estar haciéndolo mal puesto que al utilizar la función para mostrar las películas crashea.

A veces me imprime nulls al mostrar la lista de las peliculas.Hice pruebas para que imprime la primera posición del array, pero no lo hace, puesto que deduzco que se trata de un problema al recoger los datos, realmente no se por que con el **scanf** no me funciona.

Es la primera vez en esta pagina por lo que toda critica constructiva es agradecida. Adjunto código:

```
void listarpeliculascine(struct t_cine cine){
printf("hola mundo\n");
    printf("%s\n",cine.peliculas[0]);
  }

struct t_pelicula pedirDatosDePelicula(){
// No te hace falta poner la palabra "struct". Con poner t_pelicula peli es suficiente. Esta funci�n lo que hace realmente es pedirDatosDePelicula() por lo tanto... deber�a DEVOLVER los datos de la pel�cula.
struct t_pelicula peli;
printf("Introduzca el nombre de la pelicula:\n");
scanf("%s",&peli.nombre );
printf("Introduzca el director de la pelicula:\n");
scanf("%s",&peli.director );
printf("Introuzca los actores de la pelicula:\n");
scanf("%s",&peli.actores);
printf("Pelicula a%cadida con exito!\n",164);
return peli;

 }

int main() {
// TODO: Aqu� deber�as tener una variable de tipo tCine declarada. En este tCine tienes que almacenar TODOS los datos. En vez de declarar una pel�cula declara un cine con algo as�: tCine cine (no hace falta poner struct, el struct lo has declarado ya arriba de todo).
struct t_cine cine1;
struct t_pelicula peli;
int n, opcion;
int aux=0;
do{
    mostrarmenu();
    printf("Introduzca una de las siguientes opciones:\n");
    scanf("%i",&opcion );
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
        peli = pedirDatosDePelicula(); //Se asigna asi?
        //printf("%s\n",peli.nombre);
                                    cine1.peliculas[aux]=peli;
                                     aux++;
                                     break;
        case 2: listarpeliculascine(cine1);break;
            // 1. Aqu� tienes que, primero, pedir los datos de la pel�cula y devolverlos rellenados (obviamente aqu� la funci�n a la que llames no debe devolver void, sino un tPelicula. La funci�n a la que denominas "incluirpelicula"
            //    deber�a llamarse algo as� como "pedirDatos()". Este pedirDatos devolver� el tPelicula relleno.
            // 2. Una vez devuelta la pel�cula en la funci�n pedirDatos() deber�s recogerlos en una variable en el main y A�ADIRLOS al struct de tipo tCine que tienes que tener declarado al principio del main.
        case 3:
        break;
        case 4:eliminarpelicula(cine1);break;
        case 5:printf("Esta usted saliendo del programa...\n");break;
        default:
  printf("Tienes que selecionar una opcion correcta.\n" );
    }
}while(opcion!=5);
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cómo has declarado las estructura? 
(Fíjate cómo las declaras ya que tu comentario dice que no es necesario poner struct).... La variable cine, al parecer debiera ser un arreglo, por lo que si no lo has definido como tal en la declaración del struct, debieras crear la variable como arreglo:

```
tcine cine1[30];
```

Entonces la forma de acceder a las posiciones y almacenar películas en cine1, debiera ser:

```
cine1[0].peliculas = peli;
cine1[aux].peliculas = peli;
```

Esto siempre y cuando, la estructura tcine contenga una variable  del tipo t_pelicula, para que la asignación anterior se cumpla. Ya que ".peliculas" y "peli" tienen que ser del mismo tipo.